# Python data won't load properly in JavaScript Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, python, flask, leaflet

I'm trying to take user input of a home address from a text box, geocode the address, and load the data on a leaflet map. I'm getting the correct latitude and longitude, and it's appearing on my html template as intended. However, if I try to pass that python data to JavsScript, the data doesn't load. Not sure if I'm explaining this correctly; I'm very new to programming. Here's my code:

**HTML index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Examples</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>enter your address</h1> 
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="address">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML template that loads after button is clicked**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>address is {{ userlat, userlng }}</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Python/Flask file**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address = request.form['address']
        geolocator = GoogleV3()
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        userlat = location.latitude
        userlng = location.longitude
        return render_template('address.html', userlat=userlat, userlng=userlng)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Leaflet map**

```
window.onload = function () {

  var maplat = '{{ userlat }}'
  var mapltd = '{{ userltd }}'
  var map = L.map('map').setView([47.60, -122.33], 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

  L.marker([maplat, mapltd]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('your address')
    .openPopup();  

};
```

I'm sure it has something to do with var maplat = '{{ userlat }}' and var mapltd = '{{ userltd }}', but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you!

Edit: I forgot to add that I'm getting an error in the console "Invalid LatLng object: ({{ userlat }}, {{ userltd }})"

Comment: Should the lat and lng really be strings? What happens if you try var `maplat = {{ userlat }}` and the same for the lng? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Joost Hi, thanks for the help. I did try that. When I do that, I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: I also forgot to add, in my original code, I'm getting the error "Invalid LatLng object: ({{ userlat }}, {{ userltd }})"

Comment: It might be easier to not bother trying to construct a `LatLng` object with an array like that - you can construct one with `L.LatLng( x , y)`

Comment: I'm not sure of the toolchain here, but I think that `{{ userlat }}`/`{{ userlon }}` is getting replaced in the HTML template but **not** on `static/map.js`. Moving the JS code into the HTML template (inside a `<script>`) should make things work again.

Comment: @IvanSanchez That worked perfectly. Thank you. Is it possible to link {{ userlat }}/{{ userlng }} to an external JS file, or is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: I guess it's possible, but that depends on the architecture of your project/website. One approach is better for some cases, other approaches are better for some other cases.